# Get sessionStorage and restore value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, session-storage

I have an angular application with different view. On a first view I create a variable and on the second view I have to edit it.
I use for this "sessionStorage". On the first view, I record list of variable on $sessionStorage when I go to another page.

I get this data when I start second view. On this view, I want be able to edit value or not. When I click on valid button, I record the new value and when I press cancel button, I get initial value.

This is the js file of the second view.

```
angular.module('testNgStorageApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {
    var listNameRecorded = $sessionStorage.namesRecord;
    $scope.listNameTemp = listNameRecorded || [];

    $scope.edit = function(index){
        console.log("before", $scope.listNameTemp, listNameRecorded, $sessionStorage.namesRecord)
        $scope.listNameTemp[index] = $scope.newText;
        console.log("after", $scope.listNameTemp, listNameRecorded, $sessionStorage.namesRecord)
    }
...
});
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="name in listNameTemp">
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <input ng-model="newText"/>
    <button ng-click="edit($index)">Edit</button>
  </div>
```

My problem is when I edit the value ($scope.listNameTemp), $sessionStorage.namesRecords is automatically modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `$sessionStorage.namesRecords` is getting modifying is that the reference of `$sessionStorage.namesRecords` was assigned to `$scope.listNameTemp`.

You can use `angular.copy()` to void this problem. `angular.copy()` create and returns a whole new copy of the object passed to it.

**Updated Code:**

```
angular.module('testNgStorageApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sessionStorage) {
    var listNameRecorded = angular.copy($sessionStorage.namesRecord);
    $scope.listNameTemp = listNameRecorded || [];

    $scope.edit = function(index){
        console.log("before", $scope.listNameTemp, listNameRecorded, $sessionStorage.namesRecord)
        $scope.listNameTemp[index] = $scope.newText;
        console.log("after", $scope.listNameTemp, listNameRecorded, $sessionStorage.namesRecord)
    }
...
});
```